# How do I remove .0 from a db table column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I converted an Excel file into a SQL file. But, when I imported it into my database. It added .0 at the end of some values. The column type is varchar. How can I update the column values to remove .0 from all the string values?

For example:

Imported Values

```
12345.0
A119B
65489.0
BD585
123.0
124.0
12.0
```

Desired Result

```
12345
A119B
65489
BD585
123
124
12
```

Comment: If it always will be exactly 5, you can use `SUBSTRING`

Comment: Before you export from Excel you need to make sure that the column is "text" format .. Any other format (currency, number etc) can have unexpected issues ..  Verbatim from MS Excel --> *Text format cells are treated as text even when a number is in the cell.  The cell is displayed exactly as entered.*

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace `UPDATE table SET value = REPLACE(value, ".0", "")`

Comment: I wonder, will it always be `.0`? What if sometimes it becomes `.1` or `.01` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If the decimal value is not certain, you should consider using [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) ; either in `SELECT` or `UPDATE`. Now you're just showing example of `.0` but what if it has more variation than just `.0`? I assume at least that the unwanted value is always going to be after `.` so:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,'.',1) FROM mytable;

result:
+----------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,'.',1) |
+----------------------------+
| 12345                      |
| A119B                      |
| 65489                      |
| BD585                      |
| 123                        |
| 124                        |
| 12                         |
+----------------------------+
```

Use same function for the update:

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET val=SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,'.',1) 
WHERE val LIKE '%.%';
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7448d407e7251eea4cfe2875c96969f4)

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table SET colName = REPLACE(colName, ".0", "")
```

Credit goes to: @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Note: change table with your table name and colName with your column Name.